# how to declare an array globally but to set its values later?

Tags: java, arrays

i want to make use of an array thorughout my program but the values inside of the array would be set after going into a void. I know i can set the values by arr[0] but i have to set somewhat 10 names, as that will be very tedious i was looking for a better solution.

```
    class sample{
    String[] names=new String[10];
    void main(){
    names={"ram","shyam","raj","mohan","raja","adam","ramela","ramwala","ramesh","manu"};
}
}
```

This is what i tryed out but it give me an error saying that names={"ram"....}; is not a statement.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: Use `names=new String[]{"ram","shyam","raj","mohan","raja","adam","ramela","ramwala","ramesh","manu"};`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
names= new String[]{"ram","shyam","raj","mohan","raja","adam","ramela","ramwala","ramesh","manu"};
```

Array initialiser syntax can only be used at the time of variable declaration so later you have to use `new` keyword to initialise an array.

[From Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

> `An array initializer may be specified in a declaration` (§8.3, §9.3,
>   §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), `to create`
>   `an array and provide some initial values.`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the **{...}** literal declaration for arrays after they have been declared or instantiated. You will need to either assign those values during **name** declaration or loop through the array and assign values for each index.

```
String[] names = new String[10]{“ram”,...};
```

Comment: Thank you so much everybody!! Sorry for the stupid question !!